# How to create Airflow tasks dynamically from DB?

Tags: airflow

I have a list of accounts ids in a DB.
Each of these accounts ids need to be processed by Airflow.

What I've done so far is:
I created 2 DAGs:

1. **get_accounts_ids_dag**: This DAG contains 1 `PythonOperator` that retrieves the list of accounts ids from the DB, and put it in an Airflow `Variable`
2. **processing_dag**: Read the `Variable` that contains the accounts ids that was set in the previous DAG, iterate through the accounts ids, and creates `PythonOperator` for each account id

The accounts ids list in the DB is maintained by another system and is changed every once in a while.
The 1st DAG triggers the 2nd DAG.

**My questions:**

1. What do you think of that solution? Is there a better way to achieve the wanted behavior?
2. Some of these accounts ids are disabled and shouldn't be processed. If I remove these accounts ids from the list I set in the `Variable`, then in the next run of the DAG this account id won't show at all, and I would lose all of its run history. How can I avoid that?